# Deligne's letter to Bhargava from March 2004

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

I am quite interested in moduli spaces for Rings and Ideals, a letter from Deligne to Bhargava is cited in  Melanie Wood's thesis *Moduli spaces for Rings and Ideals* ([pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emmwood/Publications/WoodthesisFinal.pdf)), studying the minimal free resolution of $n$ points in $\mathbb P^{n−2}$. It's also cited in the thesis of Kevin H. Wilson, *Three perspectives on $n$ points in $\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$* ([link](http://arks.princeton.edu/ark:/88435/dsp018k71nh131)) (after Theorem 135):

> Such strong canonicity in these multiplicative structures has been implicitly used by many authors. For instance, Wright and Yukie [116] implicitly used this structure to parameterize rank $n$ rings over $\mathbb{Q}$. And Bhargava also implicitly relied on a much stronger
> canonicity (over $\mathbb{Z}$) in structuring his Higher Composition Laws [9, 10, 11, 14]. Perhaps the place where the idea of using such canonical multiplicative structures was first developed was in Deligne’s letter to Bhargava [41] which inspired Wood’s vast generalization in her thesis
> [114, 113, 112] extending Bhargava’s quadratic, cubic, and quartic Higher Composition Laws to arbitrary base schemes.

Where can I find a copy of this letter (or a short explanation of the idea)? Thank you very much.

Comment: for the record, a 2005 letter from Deligne to Bhargava is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20070221165019/http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~jbrakenh/lowrank/deligne-rostbhargava.pdf)

Comment: You would think by now there'd be some centralized effort to gather all these different "personal communications" into a central database.

Comment: They may or may not still have copies, but it would be worth writing to Deligne and Bhargava.

Comment: can you give a link to the thesis you cite, if one exists. I also found the letter @CarloBeenakker found, presumably it is not the same one you want?

Comment: Second @TheoJohnson-Freyd's suggestion. I am fairly certain Deligne is extremely organised and should still have the letter (but he may not be in the office much).

Comment: @kodlu I added links to both theses.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The letter is [here](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Emmwood/DeligneToBhargava2004.pdf).  Thanks to Will Sawin for alerting me to this request.

Comment: Welcome to MO!  Thanks for posting this.